# Creating binary tree using Racket

Tags: binary-tree, racket

'(6 (3 (2) (5)) (7 () (9))) is a sorted binary tree

Write a recursive function tree-insert that takes a tree and a number and returns the tree with the number inserted.

```
(tree-insert 8 '()) should return ‘(8)
(tree-insert 5 ‘(8)) should return ‘(8 (5))
(tree-insert 3 '(6 () (7))) should return '(6 (3) (7))
(tree-insert 4 '(6 (3) (7))) should return '(6 (3 () (4)) (7))
```

Comment: Do you have to use lists? Representing nodes of the tree with structs is a nicer approach.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I don't see a question. I wish you good luck as there is nothing to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do when dealing with a problem like this is to realise that programming as if conses were all there is is not a good idea: it makes for code which is hard to understand and hard to write.  You are processing a sorted binary tree which happens to be represented as a tree of conses.  So first of all write some abstractions.  Unfortunately the representation of the tree is kind of irregular: `(9)` is the same as `(9 ())` is the same as `(9 () ())`, and the question wants you to return the shortest version, so the abstractions need to cope with that.

Empty nodes, and the value of a node are easy:

```
(define empty-node '())
(define empty-node? null?)
(define node-value car)
```

getting the left and right elements of a node are fiddly and I have used Racket's nice `match` facility for this:

```
(define (node-left node)
  (match node
    [(or (list _ l)
         (list _ l _))
     l]
    [(list _)
     empty-node]))

(define (node-right node)
  (match node
    [(list _ _ r)
     r]
    [(or (list _ _)
         (list _))
     empty-node]))
```

And finally making a node also needs to deal with the annoying shorthand versions of nodes with empty children:

```
(define (make-node value (left empty-node) (right empty-node))
  (if (empty-node? right)
      (if (empty-node? left)
          (list value)
          (list value left))
      (list value left right)))
```

Once we have these abstractions, then `tree-insert` becomes essentially trivial to write:

```
(define (tree-insert n node)
  (cond
    [(empty-node? node)
     (make-node n)]
    [(< n (node-value node))
     (make-node (node-value node)
                (tree-insert n (node-left node))
                (node-right node))]
    [else
     (make-node (node-value node)
                (node-left node)
                (tree-insert n (node-right node)))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [***design recipe***](https://legacy.cs.indiana.edu/classes/c211/2021f-c211-000.png) for functions is:

1. data definition
2. stub, signature, purpose
3. examples/unit tests
4. template, plan
5. function definition, testing

From the example binary tree:

```
'(6 (3 (2) (5)) (7 () (9))) #|     6
                                  / \
                                 3   \
                                / \   \
                               2   5   7
                                      / \
                                         9  |#
```

one could deduce the *data definition*:

```
a TreeOfNumber is one of:   
 - empty  
 - (list Number TreeOfNumber TreeOfNumber)  
where all numbers in first TreeOfNumber <= Number, all in second >
```

A first *example/test* could be:

```
(check-expect (tree-insert 8 '()) '(8 () ()))
```

and *stub* with *signature* and *purpose*:

```
(define (tree-insert n ton) ;; Number TreeOfNumber -> TreeOfNumber
  ;; produce ton with n inserted at correct place
  (list n '() '()))
```

So the function will have the form:

```
(define (tree-insert n ton) ;; Number TreeOfNumber -> TreeOfNumber
  ;; produce ton with n inserted at correct place
  (cond
    [(empty? ton) (list n '() '()) ]
    [else ... (list ... ) ]))
```

Two more examples:

```
(check-expect (tree-insert 6  '(8 () ())) '(8 (6 () ()) ()        ) )
(check-expect (tree-insert 10 '(8 () ())) '(8 ()        (10 () ())) )
```

can be rewritten as:

```
(check-expect (tree-insert 6  '(8 () ())) (list 8 (tree-insert 6 '()) '()                  ) )
(check-expect (tree-insert 10 '(8 () ())) (list 8 '()                 (tree-insert 10 '()) ) )
```

which suggests how to complete the *definition*:

```
(define (tree-insert n ton) ;; Number TreeOfNumber -> TreeOfNumber
  ;; produce ton with n inserted at correct place
  (cond
    [(empty? ton) (list n '() '()) ]
    [else
     (if (<= n (first ton))
         (list (first ton) (tree-insert n (second ton)) (third ton))
         (list (first ton) (second ton) (tree-insert n (third ton)))) ]))
```

A few more tests:

```
(check-expect (tree-insert 5 '(8 (6 () ()) ())) '(8 (6 (5 () ()) ()) ()) )
(check-expect (tree-insert 6 '(8 (6 () ()) ())) '(8 (6 (6 () ()) ()) ()) )
(check-expect (tree-insert 7 '(8 (6 () ()) ())) '(8 (6 () (7 () ())) ()) )
(check-expect (tree-insert 8 '(8 (6 () ()) ())) '(8 (6 () (8 () ())) ()) )
(check-expect (tree-insert 9 '(8 (6 () ()) ())) '(8 (6 () ()) (9 () ())) )
```

But other examples in the question omit trailing empty trees,
so introduce a function to strip them:

```
(define (tree-trim ton) ;; TreeOfNumber -> TrimmedTree
  ;; produce ton with trailing emptys dropped
  (cond
    [(empty? ton) empty ]
    [(and (empty? (second ton)) (empty? (third ton)))
     (list (first ton)) ]
    [(empty? (third ton))
     (list (first ton) (tree-trim (second ton))) ]
    [else
     (list (first ton) (tree-trim (second ton)) (tree-trim (third ton))) ]))

(check-expect (tree-trim '(8 (6 () (7 () ())) ())) '(8 (6 () (7))) )
```

`tree-insert` could be wrapped by `tree-trim` to produce the examples in the question;
as another example of combining these functions, one could have:

```
(define (tree-insert-list lon ton) ;; ListOfNumber TreeOfNumber -> TrimmedTree
  ;; produce ton with elements of lon inserted, trailing emptys dropped
  (cond
    [(empty? lon) (tree-trim ton) ]
    [else
     (tree-insert-list (cdr lon) (tree-insert (car lon) ton)) ]))

(check-expect 
 (tree-insert-list '(22 25 7 16 8 34 67 7 32 17 8 4 5 3) '())
 '(22 (7 (7 (4 (3) (5))) (16 (8 (8)) (17))) (25 () (34 (32) (67)))) )
```

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.6 [cs].
Language: Beginning Student with List Abbreviations; memory limit: 128 MB.
All 12 tests passed!
>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
(define (tree-insert element tree)
  (cond ((empty? tree) (list element))
        ((and (>= element (car tree)) (empty? (cdr tree)))
         (list (car tree) '() (list element)))
        ((>= element (car tree))
         (list (car tree) (cadr tree) (tree-insert (caddr tree) element)))
        ((empty? (cdr tree))
         (list (car tree) (list element)))
        (else
         (list (car tree) (tree-insert element (cadr tree)) (caddr tree)))))

> (tree-insert 8 '())
'(8)
> (tree-insert 5 '(8))
'(8 (5))
> (tree-insert 3 '(6 () (7)))
'(6 (3) (7))
> (tree-insert 4 '(6 (3) (7)))
'(6 (3 () (4)) (7))
```